# How does tokenization relates to formalism, lexical grammar, and regular language?

Tags: regular-languages, programming-languages, regular-expressions, interpreters

I am reading Bob Nystrom Crafting Compiler's and in the chapter 5 it says this

> In the last chapter, the formalism we used for defining the lexical grammar—
> the rules for how characters get grouped into tokens—was called a regular
> language. That was fine for our scanner, which emits a flat sequence of tokens.
> But regular languages aren’t powerful enough to handle expressions which can
> nest arbitrarily deeply.

The thing is, in the last chapter he refers to, a tokenizer was implemented, where the core of it was using switch cases in Java.

You can find the implementation he refers to [here](https://github.com/munificent/craftinginterpreters/blob/01e6f5b8f3e5dfa65674c2f9cf4700d73ab41cf8/java/com/craftinginterpreters/lox/Scanner.java#L59)

I am failing to see how such an implementation relates to

> the formalism we used for defining the lexical grammar—
> the rules for how characters get grouped into tokens—was called a regular
> language

I mean, I did not have a feeling a formalism was defined? I also did not have the feeling I defined a lexical grammar. And apparently what I implemented alongside the book also somehow constitutes a regular language?

I guess my core issue is, I am failing to see the connection between the switch statement driven implementation I replicated, with concepts like formalism, lexical grammar, regular language etc.

I would appreciate further elucidation of these concepts and how they relate to the code in the book.

Comment: I am sure that the previous chapter describes some language that you want to parse (with keywords and operators). This forms the lexical grammar. It is quite formal in that you can tell if a text is valid mechanically, *without caring for any meaning*. You can describe this grammar with a Finite State Automaton or a regular expression, and the translation to a switch statement is natural.